# Searching for keys in dict, from list of tuple pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about dictionaries.

```
food = { 'omlette' : { 'egg': 1, 'ham': 0.2 }, 'soup' : { 'water': 1 , 'vegetables': 2, 'meat': 4 }}
```

and a list:

```
order(['omlette', 4])
```

I want to return the ingredients from `dict food(values)` times the number of servings needed. So my result should look like this:

```
{ 'egg': 4.0 , 'ham': 0.8 }
```

What should I add to this comprehension?

```
def multi(order):
    return {key for key,value in order if key in food.keys()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not a set comprehension:

```
>>> def multi(order):
...     return {k:float(v * order[1]) for k, v in food[order[0]].items()}
...
>>> multi(["omlette", 4])
{'egg': 4.0, 'ham': 0.8}
>>>
```

Comment: It will return keyError if keys is not found. >>> def multi(order):
...     return {k:float(v * order[1]) for k, v in food[order[0]].items()}
... 
>>> multi(['kfc',5])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in multi
KeyError: 'kfc'

Answer (score 1):

iCodez's answer is correct (and I upvoted it :) ). But when comprehensions get this complicated I think it's a good idea to break them down. At least for me it helps me see what's going on better:

```
def multi(order):
    d = {}
    for k, v in food[order[0]].items():
        d[k] = float(v * order[1])
    return d
```

Comment: Indeed, i am  new to python and that would be good to use in the start to not get lost.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to return `d` at the end. Edited it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def multi(order):
...     if order[0] in food.keys():
...        return { x:float(y*order[1]) for x,y in food[order[0]].items() }
...     else:return "Item not found"
... 
>>> multi(["omlette",4])
{'egg': 4, 'ham': 0.8}
```

you can aslo check if the item is in food dictionary or not

if you want to pass tuple:

```
>>> def multi(order):
...     return [ { i:float(j*y) for i,j in food[x.lower()].items() } for x,y in order if x.lower() in food.keys() ]

>>> multi([('omlette', 4),('Soup' ,1)])
[{'egg': 4.0, 'ham': 0.8}, {'water': 1.0, 'vegetables': 2.0, 'meat': 4.0}]
```

Comment: It depends on the desired behavior. Python will already throw an exception and print a message if the item isn't found. The above code changes the message and no longer exits with an error.

Comment: It also returns a `string` from a function expecting to return a `dict`, which is not ideal.

Comment: `return "Item not found"` returns a `string`, not a `dict`.